# Java - ToString Split

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, tostring

My task is to:

**1. Print out a ToString method in the following format**

"Name1", released on: Jan 01, 2013

"Name", released on: May 02, 2011

**Currently mine prints as:**

["Name1", released on: Jan 01, 2013 "Name2", released on: May 02, 2011]

**Question: How do I print it and split the array over multiple lines as adding /n does not work the way I need it to.**

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {  
       DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
       return("\"" + game + "\"" + ", " + "released on: " + date.format(released.getTime()));
 }
```

Attached is also the test case that shows how the output is accepted.

Comment: Did you try `String.format()` inside `assertEquals`?

Comment: Post `gl.toString()` method so we can help you in more detail.

Comment: Also I have no g1.toString() method the whole toString is based off that toStringTest above

Comment: First of all using StringBuilder for concatenate long String. Quicker and easy to the eyes. It seems there is a pattern with "comma", try splitting using comma as delimiter then you get the first token is title and 2nd token is released date. Hopes this help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using the `toString()` method of your list, when you have posted the `toString()` method of the element class it contains. So you need to invoke your method on each element and concatenate them with a line break, which can be done like this:

`gl.stream().map(g -> g.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a `Game` and a `GameList` class. `GameList` is something like a linked list of `Game` instances. In the `toString()` method of the `GameList` class you must iterate over that linked list and print all the values.

The method must be something like this:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (Game game = this.head; game != null; game = game.getNext()) {
        if (game != this.head)
            builder.append("\n");

        builder.append(game.toString());
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes that is correct I do have a Game Class also which I have correct for the toString test. It is literally the code I had above in my OP.

I will debug this and see what it gives me back